# Rewrite Rules nginx

Tags: nginx

I am trying to configure rewrite rules for my site running on nginx. If someone lands on the website, i want them to see contents of `mysite.com/wordpress` but the url shouldn't change, it should remain, `mysite.com`. But if someone accesses `mysite.com/some_file.php` they should be able to see that file. In my location block, when i add a 301 redirect, it works but when I add some rewrite rules they don't work and i see contents of root on example.com. Please suggest how to make rewrite rules work.

this works but with a change in url to `example.com/wordpress` (which is not desired result)

```
location = / {
    return 301 http://example.com/wordpress;
}
```

this doesn't work

PHP NGINX CONFIGURATION:

```
location = / {

    #   return 301 http://example.com/wordpress;
    # nginx configuration

    if ($http_host ~ "^(www.)example.com$"){
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /wordpress/ break;
    }
    if ($http_host ~ "^(.*).example.com"){
        rewrite ^(.*)$ http://example.com/wordpress/%1/$1 redirect;
    }
    if (!-e $request_filename){
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /wordpress/$1;
    }
    rewrite ^/(.*)index\.(php)$ http://$http_host/$1 redirect;

}
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass php;
}
```

Comment: @AD7six this means that all files with php extension should be accessed as example.com/some_file.php, these files should not be redirected to example.com/wordpress. Also when i add a redirect in server block after sever name like this  return 301 $scheme://example.com/wordpress$request_uri; the url changes to example.com/wordpress

Comment: @AD7six if location= / block only matches request for root domain, that means none of my if conditions would be true. So what i need in to specify that rewrite all requests to /wordpress/index.php?$args except for requests to .php files, any suggestion on how to do this? Thanks :)

Comment: @AD7six Thanks for giving tht hint that location = / will match only / . I now have configured rules correctly by adding try_files $uri $uri/wordpress /wordpress/ index.php?$args;  to location block and removing all other rewrites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by adding

```
try_files $uri $uri/wordpress /wordpress/index.php?$args;
```

to location / block and removing all other rewrite rules. What it does is, first it attempts to request file, then /wordpress subfolder then index.php in subfolder.

Comment: Please mark your post as correct answer in order to avoid several answers posted here. Thanks !